# Rejecting a Solution to a Modulus Question

Tags: absolute-value

Why is the solution of $|1+3x|<6x$ only $x>1/3$? After applying the properties of modulus, I get $-6x<1+3x<6x$. And after solving each inequality, I get $x>-1/9$ and $x>1/3$, but why is $x>-1/9$ rejected?

Comment: Both your inequalities have to hold, not just one of them.

Answer (score 3):

$$6x>|1+3x|\ge0\implies x>0$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Do you mind explaining your answer to me? I just started self-studying this topic and I'm not quite familiar with it yet

Answer (score 3):

You need $x$ to be both bigger than $1/3$ and bigger than $-1/9$. But clearly anything bigger than $1/3$ is automatically bigger than $-1/9$ as $1/3>-1/9$. So you only keep that solution.